# how to insert data from excel sheet to datatable in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, import, datatable

I  want to insert data from excel sheet to datatable and this was working fine. but i dont know why i am getting the following error now

**"The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly."**

My code is to Retrieve Data is

```
 if (fupExcel.HasFile)
        {
            // Get the name of the Excel spreadsheet to upload.
            string strFileName = Server.HtmlEncode(fupExcel.FileName);
            strAct = "New Schedule is uploaded, File name:" + strFileName;

            // Get the extension of the Excel spreadsheet.
            string strExtension = Path.GetExtension(strFileName);

            // Validate the file extension.
            if (strExtension != ".xls" && strExtension != ".xlsx")
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ntexl", "alert('Please select a Excel spreadsheet to import!');", true);
                return;
            }

            // Generate the file name to save.
            //string uploadFileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + strExtension;
            uploadFileName = CCMMUtility.GetCurrentDateTimeByTimeZone("US Mountain Standard Time").ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + strExtension;

            // Save the Excel spreadsheet on server.
            fupExcel.UploadFile(uploadPath, uploadFileName);

            ClsScheduleFileNew objCLSSchedule = new ClsScheduleFileNew();
            ClsScheduleFileNewProp objUserFile = new ClsScheduleFileNewProp();

            objUserFile.FileName = strFileName;
            objUserFile.FilePath = uploadFileName;
            objUserFile.CreatedDate = CCMMUtility.GetCurrentDateTimeByTimeZone("US Mountain Standard Time"); //DateTime.Now;
            ScheduleFileId = objCLSSchedule.InsertFileInfo(objUserFile);
            hdfScheduleFileId.Value = ScheduleFileId.ToString();
            if (ScheduleFileId != 0)
            {
                //ViewState["nw_Upload"] = ScheduleFileId;
            }
            else
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "err", "alert('Some error occured while exporting the file.');", true);
                return;
            }
            // Generate the connection string for Excel file.
            strExcelConn = uploadPath;

            // There is no column name In a Excel spreadsheet. 
            // So we specify "HDR=YES" in the connection string to use 
            // the values in the first row as column names. 
            if (strExtension == ".xls")
            {
                // Excel 97-2003
                strExcelConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + strExcelConn + uploadFileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;'";
            }
            else
            {
                // Excel 2007
                strExcelConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + strExcelConn + uploadFileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'";
            }
            hdfStrExcelConn.Value = strExcelConn;
            try
            {
                ImportData(uploadFileName, uploadPath, strExcelConn, ScheduleFileId);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //Delete file over here and database entry over here.
                string path = uploadPath + uploadFileName;
                CCMMUtility.DeleteFilefromLocation(path);
                objCLSSchedule.DeleteScheduleFile(ScheduleFileId);
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ntmtch", "alert('Some column values are not matched.');", true);
                return;
            }
        }
```

Improt function's code is

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow row;
        DataTable dtExcel = CreateDataTable();

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn))
        {
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1]", conn);
            da.Fill(dt);// here i am getting that error

            // Create new datatable having non empty rows
            DataTable filteredDataTable = (dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(t => t.ItemArray.Any(field => !(field is DBNull)))).CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();

            // Fill the DataTable with data from the Excel spreadsheet.
            if (filteredDataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
// my code hete to fill datatable }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
"select * from [Sheet1$]"
```

The $ is required I think.

Comment: i dont know what was the problem but it is working fine again... i have tried some other way to import data from excel to datatable 

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32370/Import-Excel-File-to-DataSet

after tried this link then i tried again my code then its work fine for me....

Answer (score 0):

Writing the solution which I have tried.

Store the excel sheet as a comma separated file and save it as a .txt

Then use the following logic to import the same into a datatable.

```
 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C://File.txt"))
        {
            String line;
            int index = -1;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                index++;
                iIndexofComma = line.IndexOf(@",");
                iLength = line.Length;
                dt.Rows.Add();
                dt.Rows[index]["col1"] = line.Substring(0, iIndexofComma);
                dt.Rows[index]["col2"] = line.Substring(iIndexofComma + 1, iLength - iIndexofComma - 1);
                dtMapping.AcceptChanges();
            }
        }
```

Hope that helps.